# Avoid repetition on HTML element, React

Tags: javascript, html, element

I have the following (simplified) HTML in my React project:

```
    const { title } = this.props;

    if(title) {
        return (
            <div class="someClass" onClick={someFunction} title={title}>
                //Whatever..
            </div>
        )
    }
    else {
        return (
            <div class="someClass" onClick={someFunction}>
                //Whatever..
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Note that the if and else return values are identical except for the title attribute.

My question is, how can I prevent this repetition, but only add `title` when required.

I know I can add title to every element and just leave it blank if not required, but I do not want title attributes all over my HTML unless they are actually doing something.

I have tried:

```
var element = (
        <div class="someClass" onClick={someFunction} title={title}>
            //Whatever..
        </div>
    )

    if(title)
        element.title = //Whatever
```

But this did not work.

I have also tried

```
element.setAttribute('title', title);
```

But this did not work either.

Both the attempts above crashed the page.

Any ideas? Surely it can be done....

Comment: `title={title? title: '' }` doesn't work?

Comment: I have tried `title = {title?title:null}` and it is working.

Comment: @AlanOmar that answer worked - if you write it as answer I will accept

Comment: sure no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use:

`title = {title?title:null}`

if there is title in your `props` this will add the attribute `title` with the specified value to the element, otherwise no `title` attribute will be added.

Answer (score -1):

1. In the `React world` with `JSX` you should use `className` instead of `class`.`HTML` doesn't exist in `React` the syntax that look like `HTML` is called `JSX` which just a `syntactic sugar`.
2. When you code hits a `return statement` everything that comes after will never be executed.So instead of doing:

if(condition){
return ...
}
else{
return ...
}

do can do:

```
if(condition){
    return (<div>...</div>);
 }
 return (<div>...</div>)
```

So you don't need the `else`

3. Stop doing manual `DOM manipulation` like in `Vanilla Javascript`by doing `element.setAttribute('title', title);` you don't need that in `React`.Please take your time to learn `React basics`.

Comment: thank you for your comments. I have downvoted as there is not an answer to my question there, just some advice on how to use React.